# Python - Search multiple columns for string to set categorical variable value

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to Python and Pandas, and am trying to use it for a statistical analysis of a very large dataset (10 million cases) because the other options (SPSS and R) are unable to handle the dataset on the authorized hardware.

In this analysis, I need to search a range of columns (30 to be exact) row-wise to extract individual strings (about 200 are possible, not sure how many will actually be present in the dataset) and then create a categorical variable for each string.

The data looks like this

```
  Dx1     Dx2     Dx3   etc... 
  001     234     456 
  231     001     444
  245     777     001
```

What is needed is

```
Dx1     Dx2     Dx3  Var001   Var234  Var456  Var231   etc..   
001     234     456  True     True    True    False
231     001     444  True     False   False   True
245     777     001  True     False   False   False
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

---

df.dtypes shows

```
AGE                      int64
DISPUNIFORM              int64
DRG                      int64
DRGVER                   int64
Readmit_30D              int64
DXCCS1                   int64
DXCCS2                   int64
DXCCS3                   int64
DXCCS4                   int64
...on to DXCCS30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to keep "one hot encoded" data set as a **sparse** matrix.

So try the following memory saving approach:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

cv = CountVectorizer()

r = pd.SparseDataFrame(cv.fit_transform(df.astype(str).add(' ').sum(axis=1)),
                       columns=cv.get_feature_names(),
                       index=df.index,
                       default_fill_value=0).add_prefix('Var')
```

Result:

```
In [85]: r
Out[85]:
   Var001  Var231  Var234  Var245  Var444  Var456  Var777
0       1       0       1       0       0       1       0
1       1       1       0       0       1       0       0
2       1       0       0       1       0       0       1

In [86]: r.memory_usage()
Out[86]:
Index     80
Var001    24
Var231     8
Var234     8
Var245     8
Var444     8
Var456     8
Var777     8
dtype: int64
```

Explanation:

I used the following trick in order to collect all data into one column:

```
In [89]: df.astype(str).add(' ').sum(axis=1)
Out[89]:
0    001 234 456
1    231 001 444
2    245 777 001
dtype: object
```

PS don't join resulting sparse DF with the source DF as it may result in "exploding" it back to normal (not sparse) DF:

```
In [87]: df.join(r)
Out[87]:
   Dx1  Dx2  Dx3  Var001  Var231  Var234  Var245  Var444  Var456  Var777
0  001  234  456       1       0       1       0       0       1       0
1  231  001  444       1       1       0       0       1       0       0
2  245  777  001       1       0       0       1       0       0       1

In [88]: df.join(r).memory_usage()
Out[88]:
Index     80
Dx1       24
Dx2       24
Dx3       24
Var001    24
Var231    24
Var234    24
Var245    24
Var444    24
Var456    24
Var777    24
dtype: int64
```

Comment: When running the code for the SparseDataFrame, "TypeError: Could not compare [' '] with block values" is returned.

Comment: @RROBINSON, can you post an output of `df.dtypes`?

Comment: The dtypes added to the question body.  They are int64 mostly.

Comment: @RROBINSON, you may want to convert them to strings first - i've updated my answer correspondingly...

Comment: Worked great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `max`, convert to `bool` and last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df = (df.join(pd.get_dummies(df, prefix_sep='', prefix='')
                .max(level=0, axis=1)
                .astype(bool)
                .add_prefix('Var')))
print (df)

   Dx1  Dx2  Dx3  Var001  Var231  Var245  Var234  Var777  Var444  Var456
0  001  234  456    True   False   False    True   False   False    True
1  231  001  444    True    True   False   False   False    True   False
2  245  777  001    True   False    True   False    True   False   False
```

Comment: I don't think this will fit in OPs memory... :(

Comment: @jezrael I can't understand ".max (level = 0, axis = 1)", why adding the level = 0 will merge the columns with the same column name, and not adding the level = 0 will calculate the maximum element of each row without distinguishing the column names? In addition, "pd.get_dummies (df, prefix_sep = '', prefix = '')" gets the index of the DataFrame is "RangeIndex (start = 0, stop = 3, step = 1)" type, it is not seen as a multi-index structure ? If it is convenient, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @AYI - If use only `pd.get_dummies(df, prefix_sep='', prefix='')` then are created duplicated columns names. So added `.max (level = 0, axis = 1)` for grouping by columns ang get max values, sum is not used because if values 1 in same columns it return 2 and indicators columns should contains only `0` or `1`. So if double `1` it return max is `1`

Comment: @jezrael The reply is very quick. Can you explain why "So added .max (level = 0, axis = 1) for grouping by columns and get max values", how does the DataFrame_obj.max method group by columns? The description of the level parameter in the official document seems to be used only in the multi-level index structure. In addition, only the DataFrame_obj.groupby method is grouped by columns in the impression.

Comment: @AyiF - Itis shorcuts for `df = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).max()` is same like `df = df.max (level = 0, axis = 1)`

Comment: @jezrael This is the first time I've touched on groupby using the keyword parameters "level and axis" at the same time. I've typed the code for a preliminary understanding. Thank you for your answer. It's worth learning.